# Angular2 beta 11 'npm install' warnings npm peerDependencies

Tags: angular, npm-install

Just installed Angular2 beta 11 `npm install angular2 --save` and got this warnings:

```
d:\Projects\sample>npm install angular2 --save
sample@1.0.0 d:\Projects\sample
+-- angular2@2.0.0-beta.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-promise@^3.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.4

npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.11 requires a peer of es6-promise@^3.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.11 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.11 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.11 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.11 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.4 but none was installed.
```

Previous Angular2 versions installed dependencies `es6-promise` `es6-shim` `rxjs` `zone.js` in to main `package.js` but now it is not.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

I checked the `..\node_modules\angular2\package.json` and can see that it is relying on these packages:

```
    "peerDependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.4"
  },
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565

NPM 3x:

> 1. peerDependencies will no longer be implicitly installed if they're
>      not already a dependency or devDependency. This is the biggest
>      change, and is the piece most likely to require developer
>      intervention.
> 2. Invalid or missing peerDependencies will be a warning instead of an
>      error. This will mean that irregularities with peerDependencies will
>      be left to developers to sort out, but peerDependency
>      incompatibilities should be less painful for consumers, because
>      installs will bail out due to dependency problems significantly less
>      frequently.

Answer (score 5):

After failing with `npm install angular2 --save` I just succeeded installing angular2 with this command:

```
npm install --save rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 reflect-metadata@0.1.2 zone.js es6-shim angular2@2.0.0-beta.17
```

If we get UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY then - after clearing the node_modules folder and removing the dependencies from package.json - we can do two things:

- install a bit earlier version of angular2
- install manually the missing dependencies

Answer (score 1):

This means that Angular2 needs these dependencies (with correct versions) to work. You need to have them in your project dependencies.

See this link for more details:

- https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/